# C# read a file outside of my project's directory

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to read a text file from my download directory so I need to give it the absolute path, but C# keeps looking in this directory: ***project/bin/Debug*** to find the file.
my OS is ubuntu and my file is in ***/home/my-name/download/file.txt***
and this is what C# is looking for: ***/project/bin/Debug/home/my-name/download/file.txt***
Is there any way to tell C# that this is an absolute path?

```
FileName = Path.Combine("/home/my-name/download/file.txt".Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines($@"{FileName}");
        
foreach (string line in lines)
{
   Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
}
```

Just to clarify; the FileName is not my problem. When I pass it to this method => File.ReadAllLines() , it adds "***project/bin/Debug***" to the beginning of FileName. So it looks for this path ⇒ ***/project/bin/Debug/home/my-name/download/file.txt*** which does not exist!

Comment: [mcve] please. Yes there is a way, but it is hard to give guidance without code.

Comment: Split() here only provides a splitting headache to guess why you used it.

Comment: I added a block of code. do you want me to share the Error as well?

Comment: remove path and split. You already have the fullpath.

Comment: @HansPassant you are right, I tried like 100 ways to make it work! that's why it doesn't make sense right now! I'll try to fix it!

Comment: @CetinBasoz it's hard coded here. but it won't be when the function gets called and i want it to work in Linux and Windows. as I said I'm new to C# and windows environment.

Comment: @user14703098, there are function to get a user's home folder (application data, common app data ... folders). Check Environment.GetFolderPath()  and Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

```
string usrPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.UserProfile, SpecialFolderOption.DoNotVerify), "YOUR NAME"); // <= home/your-name/ (also u can use Environment.UserName to get your username)
string dwnlPath = Path.Combine(usrPath, "Downloads"); // "Downloads" folder
string filePath = Path.Combine(dwnlPath, "file.txt"); // file.txt path
```

[Special folders list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqCkB.png)